# HTML input - "$" at the end of input field

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, input

I have a normal html input

```
<input class="span12" placeholder="Sample_Placeholder" name="Sample_Name" type="text">
```

in a website with bootstrap and jquery imported.

The user should enter a price in this inputfield and I just want a $-sign inside the inputbox at the right hand side.

How to do this?

Thanks in advcance :)

Comment: Add the label with $ after the textbox

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by inside. If you want it to look as if it was part of the input element, try this http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups. Else, you'll need some script to add it to the end of the value when a user stops typing, but that is going to get very tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) for input group component in bootstrap.

```
<div class="input-group">  
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price">
    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a `span` with the `$` sign on right side of the text field and using `z-index` can be placed on top of the text field.

```
.currency {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    margin-left:-20px;
}

<input class="span12" placeholder="Sample_Placeholder" name="Sample_Name" type="text">
<span class="currency">$</span>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/k24wtbk8/1/)

Comment: When you enter a lot of text it goes behind the $. If you add some right padding to the input it would prevent this. http://jsfiddle.net/k24wtbk8/3/